# how to get NFS mount vers=4.2, only 4.1 happens

Tags: nfs, nfsv4

RHEL 7.9, identical linux OS install between two servers on a 1gbps LAN

On the NFS server a `cat /proc/fs/nfsd/versions` shows  `-2 +3 +4 +4.1 +4.2`

the `/etc/nfs.conf` and `/etc/nfsmount.conf` and `/etc/sysconfig/nfs` files on both servers are unmodified; everything in them is commented out and that's how they come after a clean install from dvd of rhel-server-7.9-x86_64-dvd.iso.

on my nfs client a `mount` reports  **note the vers=4.1**

```
bkuphawk:/bkup on /bkup type nfs4
(rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.2,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.1,_netdev)
```

**how do I get v4.2 to happen?**

my `/etc/fstab` on my nfs-client is

```
bkupserver:/bkup   /bkup   nfs4   _netdev,defaults,nosuid,noexec 0 0
```

Comment: Is NFS `4.2` on the client? If so, have you tried adding `vers=4.2` to the options and then mounting it?